# Data is not showing in console even after importing

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Title: Difficulty accessing MongoDB data globally in Node.js using Mongoose

Body:

I'm encountering an issue with accessing MongoDB data globally in my Node.js application using Mongoose. Here's an overview of my setup:

I have a Mongoose file (`mongoose.js`) where I connect to my MongoDB database and retrieve data from a collection called "FoodItems". I store this data in a global variable called `food_items` for later use.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongouri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Foodb";

let food_items;

mongoose.connect(mongouri)
  .then(async () => {
    console.log('Connected to database successfully');
    try {
      const foodItemsCollection = mongoose.connection.db.collection("FoodItems");
      let data = await foodItemsCollection.find({}).toArray();
      food_items = data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error retrieving data:', error);
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error connecting to database:', err);
  });

module.exports = {
  food_items
};
```

In another file (`routes.js`), I'm importing `food_items` from `mongoose.js` and attempting to use it:

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const { food_items } = require('../config/mongoose');

router.post('/foodata', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.send({ food_items });
    console.log(food_items);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

However, when I try to access `food_items` in `routes.js`, it's empty. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You have doning it the wrong way. You are accessing the food_items directly without connecting the database first.

You need to do something like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongouri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Foodb";

let food_items;

const connectAndRetrieveData = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mongoose.connect(mongouri)
      .then(async () => {
        console.log('Connected to database successfully');
        try {
          const foodItemsCollection = mongoose.connection.db.collection("FoodItems");
          let data = await foodItemsCollection.find({}).toArray();
          food_items = data;
          resolve(food_items); // Resolve with food_items once data is retrieved
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error retrieving data:', error);
          reject(error);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Error connecting to database:', err);
        reject(err);
      });
  });
};

module.exports = {
  connectAndRetrieveData
};
```

Then you can use like:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const { connectAndRetrieveData } = require('../config/mongoose');

router.post('/foodata', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Call the function to connect and retrieve data
    const food_items = await connectAndRetrieveData();
    res.send({ food_items });
    console.log(food_items);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Hope this helps.